# How to use internal QML types from external QML files?

Tags: qt, import, qml, qtquick2

In a qrc based qml project, I have the `Internal.qml` which I can use decalratively in the `Internal {}` format.

I also have some external / remote (arbitrary location) `External.qml` which also needs to be able to use `Internal.qml` in the declarative `Internal {}` format.

However, when I try to load `External.qml`, it errors out that `Internal is not a type`.

I tried adding `qrc:/` to the import paths, but it doesn't seem to work, neither do the several import directive hacks I tried.

It doesn't seem unreasonable to expect that when the application loads an external QML file, that should be able to use the internally available QML types. What `import` directive do I need to use to get this to run?

Comment: `import "relative_path"`?

Comment: @AlexanderV impossible, the location of the external qml file is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [directory import statement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html) (it can be an absolute path)

If your `Internal.qml` path is `qrc:/internal/Internal.qml` you can do the following in `External.qml` :

```
import "qrc:/internal"

Internal {}
```

Alternatively you could define your own module with a [qmldir file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html) and do a normal module import.

Create a `qrc:/internal/qmldir` file with this content:

```
module internal
Internal 1.0 Internal.qml
```

You then need to add `qrc:/` to your import paths (when importing a module, the QML engine tries to open `<import-path>/<module-name>/qmldir` for each of the import path in its list).

After that, you can do this from `External.qml` :

```
import internal 1.0

Internal {}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution, albeit somewhat sub-optimal, is to use `QQmlComponent`:

```
  QQmlComponent c(engine);
  c.setData(readInTheRemoteQML, QUrl("qrc:/Test"));
```

The `"qrc:/Test"` part does allow the external file to properly resolve the internal types.

> If url is provided, it is used to set the component name and to
>   provide a base path for items resolved by this component.

This does the trick, but I am still open to a more "organic" solution.